# Flutter Firebase Realtime Database StreamBuilder update

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, stream-builder

I'm working on a project where I display data from Firebase Realtime Database. I use StreamBuilder to get data from database. For triggering the StreamBuilder I use
"_database.child(widget.latestPath).onValue". But sometimes I want to change the path for get another data, but when I change "widget.latesPath" the StreamBuilder doesn't refresh(Only if I use hot reaload). How can I trigger StreamBuilder to refresh the path for the new database?

Comment: Hey Gergő, this likely depends on how you implemented the listener, which is impossible for us to tell from what you shared. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and update your question. Following the guidance in there drastically increases the chances that someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DatabaseReference databaseRef;

// initState()
databaseRef = _database.child(widget.latestPath);

// build
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: databaseRef.onValue,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      // Do something with the data
  },
);

// When u want to update new path
setState(() {
 databaseRef = _database.child(widget.newPath);;
});
```