# Read values that change from Firebase on Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read and display values from my Firebase realtime database on flutter. I have managed to read and display a value from my database, but it won't get updated on my app when it's changed. I think I have to use onValue(), but I can't get it working using it.

I am using a future builder to display the data on my app, would I need it using onValue()?

```
Future getVolumesFirst() async {
  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  final snapshot = await  ref.child('path').get();
  if (snapshot.exists) {
    print(snapshot.value);
    return snapshot.value;
  } else {
    print('No data available.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `get()` you indeed get the value only once, and it doesn't monitor for updates. The Firebase documentation contains a pretty good example of [listening for updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write#read_value_events):

```
DatabaseReference starCountRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('posts/$postId/starCount');
starCountRef.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
    final data = event.snapshot.value;
    updateStarCount(data);
});
```

Alternatively, you can just use `onValue` (without `listen`) and use that value in a `StreamBuilder`.

Also see:

- other [questions about using `onValue`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bflutter%5D+onValue)
- [questions about using `onValue` with a `StreamBuilder`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bflutter%5D+onValue+StreamBuilder)

Comment: but I can't return the value in that example, so how do I display the data on my app? That's the bit I can't get

Comment: `onValue` returns a `Stream`, which you can return from your `getVolumesFirst` and then render in the UI with a `StreamBuilder`. Did you check any of the questions in the search results I linked? The code in this one looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68819555/flutter-firebase-realtime-database-streambuilder-update.